# Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space when header is fixed

Tags: html, css

In my site I have the following structure:

```
Header
Content
Footer
```

And I want to make the `Header` and the `Footer` size based on their content (not a fixed size). And the `Content` to fill the remaining space.

I saw many questions and answers like: [Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space)
that solves similar cases but in my case, the `Header` and `Footer` sizes are unknown so I can't use the `calc()` function, and the `Header` Has `position:fixed` which removes it from the layout calculations and makes the
[`flex` solutions of various kinds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979148/9977151) wrong:

---

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  position: fixed;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24979148-->

<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <p>
      <b>content</b>
      (fills remaining space)
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28771764/9977151):

---

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
.header{
   position:fixed;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28771764-->

<body>
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

---

Is there any way to do make the `Content` height = `100% - FooterHeight - HeaderHeight`
When the `Footer` and `Header` dimensions are unknown, and the `Header` has `fixed` position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a pure css solution.
since the Header is in the top , using `position: sticky` instead of `fixed` will have the same result but the layout will take it into account when calculating:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
.header{
   position:sticky;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28771764-->

<body>
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `header` is `fixed`, I think you would need to know its `height` through JavaScript, and set the `body`'s `min-height` as `100%` of the viewport's `height` minus the `header`'s height. After, you could simply use CSS Grid on `body`, to have the `content` take all the avaiblable `height`. Like so:

```js
document.body.style.minHeight=`calc(100vh - ${document.querySelector("header").clientHeight}px)`; 
document.body.style.paddingTop= document.querySelector("header").clientHeight + "px";
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:1fr auto;
}
header{
  background:lightblue;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
div{
  background:lightgreen;
}

footer{
  background:lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<header>I'm the header</header>
<div>I'm the content</div>
<footer>I'm the footer</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for pure css solution, I found that using `position: sticky` solved the problem!

Comment: Yeah `sticky` would work, thought that `fixed` was a must here. Anyway glad you have what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions based on the rather general description of your problem:

A) Use JavaScript to do the calculations for you and apply the values to margins or positions, whichever works better in your case;

B) You could repeat the contents of the header (and footer, id that's out of the document flow also) in element(s) atop the content and make it transparent and non-inter-active (pointer-events: none) - dirty, but if JS is not an option and your header does not offer some other way to determine it's height through some 'css-magic' it might be the only solution.

Quite often I find, that there are better solutions when the problem is more specifically described, so if you can tell us what elements make it impossible to know the height of the header, there might be better solutions. Often when ratios as with images are in play, vh can come to the rescue - even though tha can be tricky too...